# Flutter pub get failed

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I added `flutter_chess_board: ^0.9.4` to dependencies section of the `pubspec.yaml` file. On running `flutter pub get`, I got :

> Because chess depends on flutter_chess_board ^0.9.4 which depends on
> chess >=0.6.5 <1.0.0, chess >=0.6.5 <1.0.0 is required.So, because
> chess is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.pub get failed (1; So,
> because chess is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.)

Comment: Can you show us your ```pubspec.yaml``` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `pubspec.yaml` you have two packages which have conflicts:

```
flutter_chess_board: ^0.9.4
chess: 1.0.0+1
```

Change the version number to `any` and let flutter pick the versions of these packages which don't have conflict:

```
flutter_chess_board: any
chess: any
```

Then run `flutter pub get` and check `pubspec.lock` file and search these packages to find the version they don't have conflict on it. Update your `pubspec.yaml` and replace `any` with the proper version number you've found in `pubspec.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

Please also `add this dependency in your pubspec.yaml file https://pub.dev/packages/chess`

```
chess: ^0.6.5
```

and then again run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

If you named your project something like "Chess, flutter chess" and you get an error, change the name of the project and try again.
Try again, giving only the version number in the pubspec file.

```
dependencies: 
  flutter_chess_board: ^1.0.1
```